# Scss: text-align not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Well, I tried solving this on my own but it seems like that many people have the same problem for all sort of different reasons, so here is my situation:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <ol class="albums">
    <%= render @albums %>
  </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @albums %>
</div>
```

@album:

```html
<li id="album-<%= album.id %>" class="listed_album">
  <div class=row>
    <aside class="col-md-6" id="album_cover">
      <% if album.clips.any? %>
        <%= link_to album do %>
          <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= album.clips.first.adress %>/mqdefault.jpg" height="110" width="178"> 
        <% end %>
        <% else %>
        <%= link_to album do %>
          <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ksjfhskd4/0.jpg" height="110" width="178"> 
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </aside>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="album_info">
      <p><span class="title"><%= album.title %></span></p>
        <span class="likes">
                  <%= pluralize(Album.find(album_to_display).relationships.where(value: 1).count, "like") %> | 
                  <%= pluralize(Album.find(album_to_display).relationships.where(value: -1).count, "dislike") %>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I would like to have the title in the top-center of its col and span.likes in the bottom-left (top and bottom relative to the height of the picture in the col to the left) but until now I was only able to move it with something like padding-right: 15px; for example. How do I need to adjust it, in order to make things like text-align: center; or float: bottom; work?

```css
li.listed_album {
  #album_info {
    span.title {
      text-align: center;
    }
  span.likes {
      float: bottom;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide jS Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without being able to see it on jsfiddle or codepen.. Have you tried this:

```
li.listed_album {
  #album_info {
    text-align: center;
  }
  span.likes {
      float: bottom;
  }
}
```

or just make #album_info a flexbox:

```
#album_info {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: reviewing this answer showed my bone-head issue ... I had quoted the property, e.g., text-align: "center" which was being ignored.